# How to sort Thai language array of strings in Java

Tags: java, sorting, localization, locale, thai

Tried with Collections.sort() method - incorrect result returned

String array input is:

จัดลำดับใหม่
ย้าย
ย้ายออก
ลบ
เปลี่ยนชื่อ
เพิ่ม
แทรก

Expected output is:
เพิ่ม 
ลบ 
แทรก
ย้าย 
ย้ายออก 
เปลี่ยนชื่อ
จัดลำดับใหม่